# Should we allow theoretical questions, those asked due to curiosity?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “explain the technology to me” questions on-topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4046/are-explain-the-technology-to-me-questions-on-topic)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>   
>   
>   <sup>[The Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)</sup>

Just how strictly is that enforced? Does that exclude questions asked due to curiosity, for example where the asker wishes to know *how* or *why* something works? Do we *want* those types of questions? If yes, should we amend the FAQ?

---

At the moment, there's quite a few questions asked due to curiosity. [One way to put it](https://meta.superuser.com/a/2609/117590):

> the 'problem' the original poster faced was a 'lack of understanding'

Some of our highest voted questions were born of curiosity:

> - [What are the Windows A: and B: drives used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for)
> - [Transatlantic ping faster than sending a pixel to the screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen)
> - [How does a computer restart itself?](https://superuser.com/questions/294681/how-does-a-computer-restart-itself)
> - [Who provides the Internet service to Internet Service Providers (ISPs)?](https://superuser.com/questions/399300/who-provides-the-internet-service-to-internet-service-providers-isps)
> - [Why are we still using CPUs instead of GPUs?](https://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus)
> - [How far will you get with a 'rm -rf /'](https://superuser.com/questions/312769/how-far-will-you-get-with-a-rm-rf)
>     
>     
>     <sup>[Selected from the first page of the questions tab, sorted by votes](https://superuser.com/questions?sort=votes)</sup>

I personally think that discriminating by *actual problems that you face* is rather broad and could exclude a sizable chunk of our questions.

---

And our users have conflicting opinions too, as evidenced by the answers to [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2607/why-was-the-question-why-are-there-8-bits-per-byte-closed).

---

So, how should we deal with these?

Comment: How do you propose we deal with these?

Comment: @IvoFlipse At the moment, I'm more wondering on the community's opinion of those questions. Are they valid questions? They won't need to be *dealt with* if it's decided to change the policy towards them (and the FAQ). I'll add an answer with my own opinion tomorrow if no one else has done so (with the same opinion). I'd like to keep the question neutral (feel free to fix!).

Comment: My biggest issue with these questions is that they invite everyone to share their 2 cents and we end up with a long list of possible explanations, anecdotes or whatnot. Even though some of these questions have a clear, technical answer, which perhaps wouldn't help anyone solve direct problems, but at least teach you something about computers.
I'd be very much in favor of a solution that keeps the question, but  makes it so it doesn't invite to an endless stream of answers.

Comment: However, I don't think we need new rules, we just need to decide how we, as a community, want to enforce our existing ones.

Comment: @IvoFlipse Whichever way this ends up going, it needs to be spelt out. The current policy towards these questions is not clear. They *appear* to be disallowed by the FAQ; they are sometimes implicitly accepted, especially when popular (["depends on the mood of the crowd"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5500457#5500457)); they are sometimes closed/deleted. Depending on the interpretation, there are also a whole lot of these types of questions popping up everywhere. I would say that the only other major type of questions are the 'help' ones, which are often very localised!

Comment: I think a question I asked a while ago is quite related, and there are several older similar linked questions linked there: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4046/are-explain-the-technology-to-me-questions-on-topic

Comment: @IvoFlipse Don't we have this boilerplate text that encourages answers to have factual references, etc. like they use on Skeptics? Can't we use something like this and be a little more strict when deleting answers for these kinds of questions?

Comment: @haimg This is pretty much a duplicate then! Your question didn't come up in searches for whatever reason :/

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree that we need to fix the FAQ to clearly indicate if we allow curiosity-based question or not.

**My** opinion is that we should focus on question ***based on actual problems that you face***.

Questions that don't follow this rule are often rather bad (I'll try to find some examples later), but even the good questions get answers that are more suited to be wikipedia-articles or essays/blogposts **<sup>1</sup>** than answers.

**<sup>1</sup>**<sub><sup>(Perhaps rework some of the more popular ones and post them on our blog?)</sup></sub>

Comment: Do you suggest that the above questions are then off-topic?

Comment: @KronoS - Yes I do

Comment: I disagree with that... I feel that some question should be allowed as they're informative, and useful to know in some cases.  Of course it could be that I feel this way because one of those epic questions is mine :P

Comment: @KronoS - I wouldn't be upset if they where to stay. But I *DO* think we have to make it clear one way or the other.

Comment: @Sancho Hence another part of the question: Do these questions have value? Do we *want* these questions? And if yes, should we amend the FAQ to make that clear? The FAQ is not set in stone, it's just not easy to change.